# How to read principals and encrypted keys from Kerboros keytab file on Node JS?

Tags: node.js, encryption, kerberos, spring-security-kerberos, keytab

I need to intercept a specific request coming to my Node Server and introduce Kerberos Authentication right there.

Suppose if a request comes for /names/  ,I need to first Kerberos authenticate it and only if it authenticated successfully, I will proceed to fulfill the request.

I have one .keytab file which in my knowledge has the principals and encrypted keys which I need for authentication.

QUESTION: How can I read the .keytab encrypted file on Node JS?
I have looked into Node packages like node-krb5 and node-passport but couldn't find a way to read my keytab files

Please assist if you done something similar.
Thanks.

Comment: why does this include the [spring-security-kerberos] tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at the node [passport-negotiate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-negotiate) module which implements server side kerberos ticket authentication checking. There's a sample "login" app in the module which demonstrates how to use the module, and if you look at the [strategy.js](https://github.com/dmansfield/passport-negotiate/blob/master/lib/passport-negotiate/strategy.js) you should see how to use the underlying kerberos support, should you want to bypass passport and do authentication directly.

The actual server-side kerberos functionality is part of npm [kerberos](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kerberos) module.

Comment: FYI the changes have been incorporated into the upstream kerberos module now, and an official release has been made.

Comment: can't wait to review this.  I know NTLM/Kerberos Auth is a big thing missing from NPM.  It is probably a module that should be made paid.  BTW, feel free to update your answer, since you are saying much of the text no longer applies

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the source for node-krb5 and that's fairly useless. All it does 
is more or less what kinit does.

My guess is that you would need a node implementation of SPNEGO which a web authentication protocol that uses kerberos. None of the things in your list 
do that and it's not a trivial thing to write.

I'd suggest you look into putting a server that does support SPNEGO in front
of your node application.